# Marker differently depending on the tool with Leaflet.Editable

Tags: leaflet

I created a toolbar to add different markers with Leaflet.Editable (http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/example/index.html)
Is there a way to change the marker according to the tool used to add a marker?
How can I pass the attributes to be a `L.Control.extend` to a layer designed by Leaflet.Editable?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have found this solution:

I replaced the drawing function through the options as below
`window.LAYER = this.options.callback.call(map.editTools)`

`L.EditControl = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topleft',
    callback: null,
    icon: null,
    ...
  },
  onAdd: function (map) {
    let container = L.DomUtil.create('li', 'drawing-tool'),
    ...;
    L.DomEvent.on(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
      .on(container, 'click', function () {
    // I replaced the drawing function through the options as below
    // window.LAYER = this.options.callback.call(map.editTools);

    window.LAYER = this.options.callback.call(
        map.editTools,
        null,
        this.options
      );
    }, this);
    return container;
  }
});`